# Best practice for sanity test a K8s cluster? (ideally all from command line)

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm

I am new here, I tried to search for the topic before I post here, this may have been discussed before, please let me know before being to hash on me :)

In my project, after performing some changes on either the DevOps tool sets or infrastructures, we always do some manual sanity test, this normally includes:

1. Building a new image and update the helm chart
2. Push the image to Artifactory and perform a "helm update", and see it it runs.

I want to automate the whole thing, and try to get advice from the community, here's some requirement:

1. Validate Jenkins agent being able to talk to cluster ( I can do this with `kubectl get all -n <some_namespace_jenkins_user_has_access_to`)
2. Validate the cluster has access to Github (let's say I am using Argo CD to sync yamls)
3. Validate the cluster has access to Artifactory and able to pull image ( I don't want to build a new image with new tag and update helm chart, so that to force to cluster to pull new image)
4. All of the above can be done in command line (so that I can implement using Jenkins groovy)

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably a combination of custom Jenkins scripts (i.e. running `kubectl` in Jenkins) and some in-cluster checks (e.g. using [kuberhealthy](https://github.com/kuberhealthy/kuberhealthy)).

So, when your Jenkins pipeline is triggered, it could do the following:

- Check connectivity to the cluster
- Build and push an image, etc.
- Trigger in-cluster checks for testing if the cluster has access to GitHub and Artifactory, e.g. by launching a custom [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#job-v1-batch) in the cluster, or creating a [KuberhealthyCheck](https://github.com/kuberhealthy/kuberhealthy/blob/master/docs/CHECK_CREATION.md#creating-your-khcheck-resource) custom resource if you use kuberhealthy

During all this, the Jenkins pipeline writes the results of its test as metrics to a [Pushgateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway) which is scraped by your [Prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus). The in-cluster checks also push their results as metrics to the Pushgateway, or expose them via kuberhealthy, if you decide to use it. In the end, you should have the results of all checks in the same Prometheus instance where you can react on them, e.g. creating [Prometheus alerts](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/) or [Grafana dashboards](https://grafana.com/).